# JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

and thank you in advance for your help. I just started studying ASP.net and Entity. I wrote a post method to add a new user, but together with the user I want to add an entry to the userInfo table (first name, last name and a trifle). userInfo contains the user_id foreign key. I take it they are assigned an instance of the User class after _context.Users.Add(user). And it seems that this creates a cyclical relationship. My question is how to correctly implement adding an entry to the userInfo table (given that I need to specify the user_id foreign key), I know that this can be circumvented using Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, but it seems to me that this is not quite right.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(ReqUser user)
        {
            if (_context.Users == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'MatrixContext.Users'  is null.");
            }
            if (!ValidEmail(user.Username))
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid email");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Code))
            {
                user.ValidCode = ValidCode(user.Code);
                if ((bool)!user.ValidCode)
                {
                    var com = new Companion();
                    com.MainUserId = user.Id;
                    //тут в зависимости от кода(скорее всего стола) будем присваивать table_id
                    await _context.Companions.AddAsync(com);
                }
            }
            //user.Password = Convert.ToString(user.Password.GetHashCode()); хэширование пароля
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (UserExists(user.Id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo { CreatedAt = DateTime.Today, Name = user.Name, Surname = user.Surname, Code = user.Code, UserId = user.Id };
            _context.UserInfos.Add(userInfo);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                    return Conflict();
            }
            //user.ValidCode = !ValidCode(user.Code);
            return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
        }
```

Comment: There are some problems with that code. For one, `_context.Users` cannot be `null`. It's also a terrible idea to check for an existing user by inserting blindly and catching. This isn't just a pedantic concern `DbUpdateException` is far too broad to imply something so specific

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for the comments. I saw the null check in some examples and decided that it would not be superfluous, but I really think about deleting it. Can you tell me what's wrong with my try catch block? After all, I do not check the existence of the User (for this I have a separate UserExist method) I save the changes to the database and in catch catch there are errors updating the database. If there are better ways, I will be glad to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a structure like this in your entity model:

```
public class User
{
    //other properties
    public virtual List<UserInfo> userInfos { get; set; }
}
public class UserInfo
{ 
    //other properties
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

This causes a reference cycle.

The solution is what you mentioned, use `Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`.

Of course, you can also ignore the navigation properties that cause the JSON serialization cycle, use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to modify one of the navigation properties, which instructs Json.NET not to traverse the navigation properties when serializing.

For more detail, you can refer to the official document: [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization).